# Jquery is not working although it is loaded

Tags: jquery

jQuery functions like `datepicker()`, `val()`, or `hide()` etc. don't work. I have no idea why is that so, because alert before the command works, as well as jQuery variable is defined.

What libraries I have loaded?:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("bundles/admin/js/plugins/jquery-1.7.min.js") }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("bundles/admin/js/plugins/jquery.flot.min.js") }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("bundles/admin/js/plugins/jquery.flot.resize.min.js") }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("bundles/admin/js/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js") }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("bundles/admin/js/custom/general.js") }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("bundles/admin/js/custom/dashboard.js") }}"></script>
```

Where does the function I'm trying to run resides? Inside `dashboard.js` file, the code looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#datepicker').hide();
});
```

And the datepicker field is:

```
<input type="text" id="dateBir" name="dateBir" id="datepicker" />
```

I've tried that with $ sign instead of jQuery variable, but nothing happens. Alert before the function works, jQuery is defined, just like I said at the beginning. What's wrong?

Comment: The .js file contains jQuery(document).ready(...)

Comment: What do you use for debugging? are you getting any errors ?

Comment: firebug, but it doesn't show any errors here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two id's on your input, change datepicker to be a class?

```
<input type="text" id="dateBir" name="dateBir" class="datepicker" />
```

Can you then run from developer console?

```
jQuery('.datepicker').hide();
jQuery('.datepicker').css('display','none');
jQuery('#dateBir').css('display','none');
```